# Unable to download a report on rsconnect

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Dear R Community I need your help regarding shiny. I am getting an error downloading a report when the app is deployed on shiny and rsconnect. But locally it is working fine. I have attached the log:

> Warning in file(con, "w") : Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
> x

```r
library(shiny)
library(sdcMicro)


ui <- fluidPage(    
  titlePanel("Sample SDC Report"),
  uiOutput("ui_export_report")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  data(testdata)
  sdcObj <- createSdcObj(
    testdata,
    keyVars = c('urbrur', 'roof', 'walls', 'water', 'electcon', 'relat', 'sex'),
    numVars = c('expend', 'income', 'savings'), w = 'sampling_weight'
  )
  
  output$ui_export_report <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(column(12,  
                    shiny::downloadButton("myRepDownload", "Save report", btn.style = "primary"), align = "center"
    ))
  })
  
  output$myRepDownload <- shiny::downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("sdcreport-", Sys.Date(), ".html")
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      sdcMicro::report(
        sdcObj,
        outdir = tempdir(),
        filename = "tmp",
        title = "SDC-Report",
        internal = TRUE,
        verbose = FALSE
      )
      f_tmp <- file.path(tempdir(), "tmp.html")
      on.exit(file.remove(f_tmp))
      file.copy(from = f_tmp, to = file)
    }
  )  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check if you have all permissions needed in the file directory?

Comment: Yes, I have all permission